# Why does the value of input field return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on a way to change content of the page.

I run the script. I am able to change the text once by double clicking on the paragraph but second time it returns undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".editable").dblclick(function(){
    var id = $("this p").attr('id');
    $(this).html("<input id="+id+" type='text'>");
    $(this).keyup(function(event){
      if (event.which == 13){
        //alert(id);
        var valT = document.getElementById(id).value;
        $(this).html("<p id='"+id+"'>" + valT + "</p>");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable" ondblclick="">
  <p id="asd">first Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("p", this).attr('id');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two problems in your code. Firstly, the selector of the id and secondly, the keyup event gets made every time you click.
The code below will unset the keyup event before creating a new one.

https://jsfiddle.net/24kjchxj/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".editable").dblclick(function(){
    var id = $(this).find("p").attr('id');
    $(this).html("<input id="+id+" type='text'>");
    $(this).off('keyup');
    $(this).keyup(function(event){
      if (event.which == 13){
        //alert(id);
        var valT = document.getElementById(id).value;
        $(this).html("<p id='"+id+"'>" + valT + "</p>");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that whenever your double click event trigger, it register new onkeyup event. Try to replace your code with the following one:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                var id;
                $(".editable").dblclick(function(){
                  id  = $(this).find('p').attr('id');
                    $(this).html("<input id="+id+" type='text'>");

                });

                $("body").on("keyup", ".editable input", function(event){

                    if (event.which == 13){
                      var valT = document.getElementById(id).value;
                      $(".editable").html("<p id='"+id+"'>" + valT + "</p>");
                    }
                });

            });
```